# Python For loop and BeautifulSoup results into CSV

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have scraped address data from a site using a For loop which prints out the result. I would like to output all of the results from each of the For loops into separate columns in a CSV file. When I try to output I only get the last iteration through the For loops and all of the bulky HTML code is included. The `print street.text` prints all of the data located within all span tags that have `itemprop = address`.

Here is my code so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml");

for address in soup.find_all('span', {'itemprop' : 'address'}):
    print address.text
```

HTML in question:

```
<span itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1576"><a href="/homedetails/403-James-Toney-Dr-Elon-NC-27244/96315551_zpid/" class="hdp-link routable" title="403 James Toney Dr, Elon, NC Real Estate" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1575"><span itemprop="streetAddress" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1574">403 James Toney Dr</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Elon</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1580">NC</span><span itemprop="postalCode" class="hide">27244</span></a></span>
```

This prints all of the data in order. However I need to get each instance of address into a CSV column. Is this possible? I was thinking I needed a way to store each address into a variable as the loop iterates, but I've read that this might not be a good solution.  I've looked on several websites trying to figure out a solution. I feel like it should be pretty simple, I just can't figure it out.

Edit: I was able to use only 1 loop to get all of the info I need. Hopefully this makes the problem simpler.

Comment: Show the relevant part of html source or share the link to the website.

Comment: I am not sure why you think this makes it simpler. Could you show an example of the HTML?

Comment: @alecxe I've included the source HTML I'm interested in, is there enough info there?

Comment: @Krumelur I posted the HTML. I think it's simpler to deal with 1 loop rather than 4, that was my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the output I wanted using this:

```
addresses = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml" );

for address in soup.find_all ('span', {'itemprop' : 'address'}):
    addresses.append(address.text)

file = 'output.csv'
with open(file,'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(addresses)
```

Thanks everyone for the help! The lengths of the address are not all the same but it didn't seem to make a difference. All of the addresses were outputted in their full length.

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to give an example of the HTML to give a correct answer.

In the special case of there always being exactly the same amount of each and they correlate in order, you could use the `zip` function, e.g.

```
streets = [street.text for street in soup.find_all(...)
towns = ....
states = ....
zips = ....

recs = zip(streets,towns,states,zips)

c = csv.writer(...)
for rec in recs:
    c.writerow(rec)
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include only the 1 loop. I also included the part of the HTML source I'm interested in. I think that makes the process easier, can you explain how this would work with just 1 For loop?

Comment: Looking at the HTML, I think the best way is to nest it, e.g. using "address" for looping then getting each element starting with the address `span`.

Comment: That is exactly what I did . I used a dictionary, `addresses = []` and looped through the address and appending each address.text to my dictionary. Then I simply used `writer.writerow(addresses)` to get the CSV output I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this where you have parallel list, or a dictionary of lists (up to you), this will only work if they are the same size though, you didn't specify so this should work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
response = '<span itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1576"><a href="/homedetails/403-James-Toney-Dr-Elon-NC-27244/96315551_zpid/" class="hdp-link routable" title="403 James Toney Dr, Elon, NC Real Estate" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1575"><span itemprop="streetAddress" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1574">403 James Toney Dr</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Elon</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion" id="yui_3_15_0_1_1405702066072_1580">NC</span><span itemprop="postalCode" class="hide">27244</span></a></span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

addressList = soup.find_all('span', {'itemprop' : 'address'})

with open('addresses.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for address in addressList:
        writer.writerow([address.text])
```

Comment: I updated my question. I only need 1 loop. Would this work using just the 1 loop?

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed. This solution outputted a CSV file with a column for each character in the address. I adapted your answer from before and it worked great. I'll post my answer.

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I wrote this on my phone so I didnt get to test it and cool! I'd like to see how you did it

Comment: No worries, I wouldn't have figured out the solution had you not made that original posting! My answer is now posted.

Comment: Ah I know why! @Steve I forgot to put square brackets somehwere! Now it should be all good

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution.

The idea is to use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class and rely on the fact that all of the fields you need in csv are presented with `span` tags with `itemprop` attribute:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """your html here"""
fieldnames = ['streetAddress', 'addressLocality', 'addressRegion', 'postalCode']

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
    for address in soup.find_all('span', itemprop='address'):
        writer.writerow({element['itemprop']: element.text
                         for element in address.find_all('span', itemprop=True)})
```

After executing, the contents of `output.csv` for the HTML source you've provided is:

```
403 James Toney Dr,Elon,NC,27244
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I ultimately ended up using a different answer for now, but as my project expands I might end up using this method.